# How to set up SharePoint Online Managed (term set) Navigation with auto update of new sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, managed-metadata

We have a SharePoint Online site collection, which has about 7 Sites that each have at least 5 subsites, and potentially more below that.

I've recently discovered that our site loading super slow is [due to the Structural Navigation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/navigation-options-for-sharepoint-online) (Global) used in our site. Basically, our only option is to use a different type of navigation.

I've been looking into creating [Managed Navigation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-au/SharePoint/administration/overview-of-managed-navigation) for our site.

What I don't understand is:

- **How do you generate the term-sets based on the current structure of the site?**

  - Will we have to create each term set for each site/subsite from scratch?
- **How do you make sure that once the term-sets are set up, they update automatically when a new subsite is created?**

  - Will we have to manually update the term-sets to include the new site(s)?